# Interacting with an API using JWT

Tags: api, jwt

How do I interact with an API using JWT. 
I've been given an API url, an integration key and a bearer, and I've been told to get my token with "POST integration key"
I need to get data out of there system and into our MS SQL database, preferably using an SSIS package.

I've used a REST API using curl before to update and get my IP address, I just had to set up an API key through the website and run a command like the below.

```
curl -u abcdabcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdabcdabcd:x -X GET https://web.site.com/api/v1/addresses.json
```

I understand what JWT is a little, as in it's encoded as  header.payload.signature, but i'm confused as to how do I get the data out of there system into mine using one.

- What is the bearer I've been given?
- Will I have to use my integration key and bearer to get a JWT from there system?
- Will I then use that JWT to interact with there API?
- Will it be as simple as the curl command above or will I need to write a script using one of the libraries on jwt.io

Answer (score 0):

Eventually after about 10 emails between the supplier/developer asking for proper documentation and him telling me his system uses JWT, he sent me screenshots of how he tests the API using postman. From his screenshots I was able to figure out what needs to be done, below is my powershell implementation if it benefits anyone.

```
#$fromdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)  
$fromdate = '01/01/2016'

[string]$body = '{"IntegrationKey":"abcdabcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdabcdabcd"}'

$URI = "https://web.site.com/api/token"
# -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

[string]$jwt = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Method post -ContentType 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' -Body $body

$headers = @{"Authorization"="Bearer "+ $jwt.replace("`"","")}

$uri = "https://web.site.com/api/GetData?startDate=" + $fromdate
$response = ".\ResponseData.json"

Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Method get -Headers $headers -TimeoutSec 6000 -OutFile $response
```